# Difference between OWL 2 DL and OWL 2 Full in practice

Tags: owl

How to quickly check whether the selected domain ontology is OWL 2 DL? I mean with what method I can chcek if the ontology is OWL 2 DL and not e.g. OWL 2 Full?

The additonal sub-question to my question is a full list of differences between OWL 2 DL and OWL 2 Full

Comment: use an OWL profile checker. Regarding the second question, as stated in the W3C docs: *""OWL 2 Full" is used informally to refer to RDF graphs considered as OWL 2 ontologies and interpreted using the RDF-Based Semantics."*

Comment: Which OWL profile checker do you suggest?

Comment: I don't know., would just take one based on OWL API, e.g.  https://github.com/stain/profilechecker